# Can I restrict access to the tplink wifi network to anyone except specified set of Mac addresses?

Tags: mac-address

I have the router TP-Link N750 (TL-WDR4300).

I'm familiar with the Mac addresses filtering but I need to restrict all user from joining the network not from Internet after joining the network, so one can't join the network unless its MAC address is explicitly written or specified somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. See this doucment, page 43
http://www.tp-link.com/resources/document/TL-WDR4300_V1_User_Guide_19100.pdf